# Como arredondar com 2 casas decimais no javascript utilizando uma regra específica?

Tags: javascript, matemática

Olá. preciso fazer um simulador em que um aluno insira a nota 1, a nota 2 e ele calcule a média.

A nota 1 é multiplicada por 0,4 e a nota 2 por 0,6.

As notas são decimais e somente a segunda casa depois da vírgula é arredondada.

Ex: 4,46 - arredonda para 4,5

o problema é que segundo o critério da instituição, se a segunda casa for até 4, ele arredonda para para baixo (4,94 -> 4,9) e se for de 5 para cima, arredonda pra cima (4,95 -> 5,0).

Estou usando a função

```
var  mediaFinal = Math.round(media_sem_arrend * 10) / 10;
```

Nas funções de arredondamento padrão, até 5 ele arredonda para baixo e a partir de 6 ele arredonda pra cima.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão?

Grato.

Answer (score 6):

Utilize a função [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var n1 = 2.34;
var n2 = 2.35;

console.log(n1.toFixed(1)); //2.3
console.log(n2.toFixed(1)); //2.4
```

Se for necessário fazer mais operações com o resultado, é preciso convertê-lo para `float` novamente utilizando a função [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), uma vez que a função [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) resulta em uma `string`.

```
var n = 2.35;
var x = n.toFixed(1);
n = parseFloat(x);

console.log(n+1); //3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma função de arredondamento usando Math.floor. A função permite passar o número de casas decimais que você deseja arredondar.

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
var arredonda = function(numero, casasDecimais) {
  casasDecimais = typeof casasDecimais !== 'undefined' ?  casasDecimais : 2;
  return +(Math.floor(numero + ('e+' + casasDecimais)) + ('e-' + casasDecimais));
};
```