# Casas decimais em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Sou novato em programação, fiz uma conta de divisão e queria reduzir as casas decimais.

Segue abaixo o meu código!

```js
document.write("A média de gerações que se passaram é: " + (2019/28));
```

> **Obs:** resultado 72.10714285714286.

Queria reduzir esse número para duas casas apenas, como faço?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: @LeAndrade não acho que seja duplicada dessa pois não tem a ver com problemas de erros na maneira como JavaScript se comporta em cálculos matemáticos. `2019 / 28` é mesmo um numero com muitas casas decimais .

Comment: @Sergio tudo bem retirei meu voto, embora, creio que na primeira resposta está bem claro como pode-se setar casas decimais em javascript com toFixed().

Comment: Possível duplicata de [JavaScript gerando float com várias casas decimais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29318/javascript-gerando-float-com-v%c3%a1rias-casas-decimais)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como arredondar com 2 casas decimais no javascript utilizando uma regra específica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114740/como-arredondar-com-2-casas-decimais-no-javascript-utilizando-uma-regra-espec%c3%adfi)

Answer (score 9):

Podes usar o [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) para limitar as casa decimais:

```js
const nr = 72.10714285714286;

console.log(nr.toFixed(2)); // dá 72.11
console.log(nr.toFixed(4)); // dá 72.1071
```

Se quiseres usar no formato de numero (e não String como o `.toFixed` retorna) podes converter de volta para Number com `Number`... ou seja:

```js
const nr = 72.10714285714286;

console.log(typeof nr); // number
console.log(nr.toFixed(2)); // dá 72.11
console.log(nr.toFixed(4)); // dá 72.1071

console.log(typeof nr.toFixed(2)); // string

const arredondado = Number(nr.toFixed(2));
console.log(typeof arredondado, arredondado); // number 72.11
```

Answer (score 4):

Multiplique por 100, utilize a função `Math.round()` e divida por 100.

`document.write("A média de gerações que se passaram é: " + Math.round(2019/28*100)/100);`

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser reduzir, use `.toFixed(n)` onde `n` é a quantidade de casas decimais.
Se quiser eliminar as casas decimais, `Math.trunc(x)` onde `x` é o numero a ser truncado.