# Transformar em números strings contendo pontos e vírgulas

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma chamada AJAX e está me retornando uma array de objetos da seguinte maneira:

```
[
  {
    "area": "607,55"
  },
  {
    "area": "2.415,67"
  },
  {
    "area": "280,53"
  },
  {
    "area": "203,05"
  },
  {
    "area": "296,13"
  }
]
```

Eu gostaria de somar todas as áreas, e estou fazendo da seguinte forma utilizando o `.replace` para trocar a vírgula:

```
let calculaArea = [];     
   result.forEach(function (result) {

         calculaArea.push(parseFloat(result.area.replace(/,/,'')));

       });
//console.log(calculaArea)
[
  60755,
  2.41567,
  28053,
  20305,
  29613
]
/////retornando array com numeros sem virgula/////
```

Em seguida estou somando a array de objetos assim:

```
 let totalArea = calculaArea.reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return (a + b);
              });
///console.log(totalArea);
///
138728.41567000002
///
```

Já dei uma olhada em várias respostas aqui porém os mesmos só trabalha com poucas casas - exemplo: `3.28 = 3,28`.

Existe algum um método mais eficaz pra somar array que contenha pontos e vírgulas, e que mantenha 2 casas depois da vírgula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo a documentação, [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) considera que o ponto é o separador das casas decimais. Sendo assim, não basta remover a vírgula, pois o segundo número passa a ser `2.41567`, que é interpretado como 2,41567 e não é isso que queremos.

Então o jeito é primeiro fazer um `replace` para remover todos os pontos, e no final trocamos a vírgula por ponto:

```js
let valores = [
  {
    "area": "607,55"
  },
  {
    "area": "2.415,67"
  },
  {
    "area": "280,53"
  },
  {
    "area": "203,05"
  },
  {
    "area": "296,13"
  }
];

let total = valores
    // transforma as strings da área em números
    .map(v => parseFloat(v.area.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')))
    // somar tudo e arredondar para duas casas decimais
    .reduce( (a, b) => a + b).toFixed(2);
console.log(total);

// ou, se quiser formatar o valor para usar pontos como separador de milhares e vírgulas como separador decimal
let totalNum = valores
    // transforma as strings da área em números
    .map(v => parseFloat(v.area.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')))
    // somar tudo e arredondar para duas casas decimais
    .reduce( (a, b) => a + b);
console.log(Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(totalNum));
```

O primeiro `replace` usa `\.` para pegar todos os pontos da string (a *flag* `g` indica que quero substituir todas as ocorrências, já que podemos ter valores acima de 1 milhão podem ter mais de um ponto). O segundo `replace` troca a vírgula por ponto, e no final temos a string no formato que `parseFloat` entende.

Note que a ordem é importante. Por exemplo, se tivermos a string `1.234,56`:

- se eu trocar primeiro a vírgula por ponto, ela passa a ser `1.234.56`, e se eu remover os pontos, ela vira `123456` (mais cento e vinte mil, um valor completamente diferente do original).
- trocando primeiro o ponto, ela vira `1234,56`, e trocando a vírgula por ponto, ela passa a ser `1234.56`, que `parseFloat` interpreta corretamente como sendo "mil duzentos e trinta e quatro, vírgula, cinquenta e seis".

Depois basta somar e usar [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) para arredondar o resultado para duas casas decimais. Lembrando que `toFixed` de fato [arredonda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/114748/112052) (`2.345` arredondado para duas casas vira `2.35`).

Vale lembrar também que `toFixed` retorna uma **string**. Se quiser o valor numérico, pegue o retorno de `reduce` diretamente. Só não se esqueça [desse detalhe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/112052).

---

Também incluí uma segunda opção, para formatar o valor numérico usando o ponto como separador de milhares e vírgula como separador decimal (além de considerar sempre duas casas decimais). Para mais detalhes, veja a [documentação de `NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

Comment: amigo @hkotsubo muito obrigado também testei seu código alterando algumas coisas e funcionou perfeitamente, queria saber se e possivel com esse resultado  adicionar a "," virgula para ficar float real neste exemplo "3.802,93" obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: @luiz_vitorr Atualizei a resposta com essa opção. E só para lembrar como o site funciona: se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: obrigado @hkotsubo estarei positivando a resposta e dizer que você foi de grande ajuda pelas dica

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar um valor em javascript, eu transformo em `Number` dessa maneira.

```
 vp = Number(ValorTotalPedido.replace(/[R\$ \.]/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
```

Você teria que fazer mais ou menos assim:

```
 calculaArea.push(Number(result.area.replace(/[R\$ \.]/g, '').replace(',', '.')));
```

Tente desta maneira. Você vai ter que configurar quando estiver passando o parâmetro.

Comment: obrigado mariana sua resposta funcionou perfeitamente, eu iria pergunta logo em seguida como fazer pra colocar as 2 casas decimais depois da virgula.. o outro amigo @hkotsubo respondeu logo a cima.. então voces 2 me ajudaram muito!!

Comment: @luiz_vitorr que bom que te ajudou. Estamos as ordens.